# Regex first digits occurrence

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

My task is extract the first digits in the following string:

```
GLB=VSCA|34|speed|1|
```

My pattern is the following:

```
(?x:VSCA(\|){1}(\d.))
```

Basically I need to extract "34", the first digits occurrence after the "VSCA". With my pattern I obtain a group but would be possibile to get only the number? this is my c# snippet:

```
string regex = @"(?x:VSCA(\|){1}(\d.))";
Regex rx = new Regex(regex);
string s = "GLB=VSCA|34|speed|1|";

if (rx.Match(s).Success)
{
    var test = rx.Match(s).Groups[1].ToString();
}
```

Comment: If the string is always in that format, why not just split on `|` and take the `1` index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match `34` (the first digits after `VSCA`) using a positive lookbehind `(?<=VSCA\D*)` to assert that what is on the left side is `VSCA` followed by zero or times not a digit `\D*` and then match one or more digits `\d+`:

[`(?<=VSCA\D*)\d+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dVSCA%5cD*%29%5cd%2b&i=GLB%3dVSCA%7c34%7cspeed%7c1%7c)

If you need the pipe to be after `VSCA` the you could include that in the lookbehind:

[`(?<=VSCA\|)\d+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dVSCA%5c%7c%29%5cd%2b&i=GLB%3dVSCA%7c34%7cspeed%7c1%7c)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VVBY27790)

Comment: I hadn't seen your answer when I posted mine. Thanks to typing out the answer and forgetting to submit. I've upvoted yours

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern: `(?<=VSCA\|)\d+?(?=\|)` will match only the number. (If your number can be negative / have decimal places you may want to use `(?<=VSCA\|).+?(?=\|)` instead)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Regex for this, you can simply split on the `'|'` character:

```
string s = "GLB=VSCA|34|speed|1|";

string[] parts = s.Split('|');

if(parts.Length >= 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(parts[1]); //prints 34
}
```

The benefit here is that you can access all parts of the original string based on the index:

```
[0] - "GLB=VSCA"
[1] - "34"
[2] - "speed"
[3] - "1"
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eP8cFH)

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers work really well, if you really must use a regular expression, or are interested in knowing how to get to that straight away you can use a named group for the number. Consider the following code:

```
string regex = @"(?x:VSCA(\|){1}(?<number>\d.?))";
Regex rx = new Regex(regex);
string s = "GLB:VSCA|34|speed|1|";

var match = rx.Match(s); 
if(match.Success) Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["number"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `(?<=VSCA\|)[0-9]+`?

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/00FYEn/1)